# why error % is not correct when Duration Assertion is used

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a problem with Duration Assertion. I have set the Assertion Duration for contentdetail_request to 1000ms.

[image]

Now looking at the SynthesisReportGui.CSV, I can see the maximum taken for that request is less than 1000. But still, the error % is shown as 100. Why is this?

[image]

Or is there anything wrong in my understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot it be connected with the [embedded resources processing by JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/differentiating-response-times-jmeter-embedded-resources)? For instance main request is completed in 60 seconds and one of sub-requests takes longer?

[image: JMeter Embedded Resources]

If this is the case, you should change your [Duration Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion) scope to look into `Main sample only` as given embedded resources calls are made in parallel (if not, tick "Parallel downloads" box as this is how real browsers operate)